# how to stream a live video using gst-launch with fliping option

Tags: video, video-streaming, media-player, gstreamer, live-streaming

I am trying to steam a live video which I am playing from a server .. this server uses Gstreamer so I figured let me use gst-launch to play it. Now I need to play it and at the same time flip the video because the streaming I am getting is upside down. I have successfully done that using vlc, but not so using gst-launch !!!

this is the command in gstreamer :

```
gst-launch  playbin uri=file:///home/Desktop/video.sdp ! videoflip method=clockwise ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink
```

and I get this error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link playbin0 to videoflip0
```

Also, I would like to ask if anyone know how to reduce the latency in a live streaming and avoid the lagging in buffering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
gst-launch uridecodebin uri=file:///home/Desktop/video.sdp ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoflip method=clockwise ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

Uridecodebin will parse and decode your input until raw format, while playbin is a full pipeline and has no pads to link to, it will handle decoding (it uses uridecodebin internally) and displaying the media to you. It has to be used as standalone element. You can try this, though:

```
gst-launch playbin2 uri=file:///home/Desktop/video.sdp video-sink="videoflip method=clockwise ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink"
```

It might work, too.

Comment: Hello again, the video output that I get is very jittery, do you think that the flipping command compromise quality with latency ?

Answer (score 0):

try it :
gst-launch filesrc location=/home/Desktop/video.sdp ! sdpdemux ! videoflip method=vertical-flip ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink

Comment: it gives me this error: Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2625): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
Execution ended after 217511749 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: try it : gst-launch -vvv playbin uri=file:///home/Desktop/video.sdp  and send me all information that gstreamer will return.